# props not being updated properly in Login page button action with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux

I am working on a Login page where on click of submit button I do some backend api operation and return success/failure. I am able to receive a successful response in my mapStateToProps function but it is not reflected in then part of my api call.
Following is my mapStateToProps function:

```
Login.propTypes = {
  isLoggedIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {login})(Login);
```

My submit button action:

```
    const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {
      dispatch(login(username, password))
        .then(() => {
          setLoading(false);
          if (props !=null && props.isLoggedIn) {
            props.history.push("/home");
          }
        })
        .catch(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

props.isLoggedIn is still false even when I receive it as true from the action. Although when I click on the submit button, the user is able to login. So I assume that state is somewhere updated but not reflected in the then function of API call.

Comment: Check the logs using redux dev tools. There must be something missing in your action or reducer.

Comment: Hi, I just checked the state in the Redux tab, it has isLogged = true but I think it is not being correctly set into props

Answer (score 0):

I think you're checking the value of isLoggedIn before it actually gets changed by your action in the state (this operation runs asyncronously).

I'd suggest you to dispatch your login and then check the isLoggedIn separately in a useEffect, something like

```js
const {isLoggedIn} = props;
const handleLogin = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {
    dispatch(login(username, password))
      .then(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  } else {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};

useEffect( () => {
  // This hook will run every time isLoggedIn changes value
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    props.history.push("/home");
  }
}, [isLoggedIn])
```

Comment: I used your code and it works great now but I am also getting the following error in the console: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Login (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)

Comment: can you help me with this?

Comment: I think this has more to do with how you are including your Login component, make sure it doesn't render if not needed